# C# Winforms filter datagridview from dynamicly created controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I create base `Form` class where i create default style, default panels, datagridview and toolbars. 
When i create new specific form i extend that base abstract class and new class automaticly have toolbar, datagridview and filter. In new form i just pass datagridview datasource and i have full result for all my forms. I dont waste time to create new panels, new toolbars , new styles etc....

So all that work problem start in filtering grid:

When i create grid i also create controls for filtering data in grid based on grid columns.
So i get columns colections and based on grid column type i generate in sidebar control and label  for that column.

Here is code how i genrate controls based on grid columns:

```
   public void InitializeDefaultDataGridViewFilter()
    {
        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in _dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            i++;

           // RowStyle temp = _tableLayout.RowStyles[_tableLayout.RowCount - 1];
            _tableLayout.RowCount++;
            _tableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));

            _tableLayout.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = col.HeaderText, TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight }, 0, _tableLayout.RowCount - 1);

            if (col is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)
            {
                TextBox textBox = new TextBox()
                {
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    Name = col.Name
                };

                _tableLayout.Controls.Add(textBox, 1, _tableLayout.RowCount - 1);
            }

            else if (col is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox()
                {
                    Name = col.Name,
                    CheckState = CheckState.Checked
                };
                _tableLayout.Controls.Add(checkBox, 1, _tableLayout.RowCount - 1);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

And i also create `Button` that i put below filter and create event

```
private void filterButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // here now i need to filter
}
```

Now here is problem: How now to know which controls is filled? ID, NAME, PIB...Etc?
How determine which controls has value and that controls value use to filter grid.

I know how to filter grid but i dont know how to determine which dynamic controls have value and that control use to filter specific column in grid.

If dynamic textbox for `ID` has value `1232` filter grid for that column.

[image]

Comment: Problem 1 - you are working off DGV column. Try working with `DataTable` and `DataView`. Problem -2. if you want to control your controls, add them to a collection, which you can then iterate and check their states

Comment: keeping your control instances in a dictionary is ideal, also, you can iterate over your controls by `foreach(Control filterControl in _tableLayout.Controls)` and by ignoring labels, you can see if it is a text box, and if not empty, then can get the Name of it since it equals the column name and execute the filter on that column. (value checking should be different for checkbox, obviously)

Comment: So i need to create `DataTable` with columns names and that `DataTable` to push in dvg columns? And than when i want to generate filter controls i need to add them in `Dictionary` and that filed to use in click event  to filter data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, it may be a better approach to get the column “types” from the data source the grid uses instead of the grid itself and also make a “collection” of the controls used to “filter” the grid.

It is possible to loop through the `_tableLayout.Controls` and gather up the controls you need to filter, however, “loping through the ALL the controls” each time the user “filters” the data appears unnecessary since the controls do not change with each filter operation. Hence the suggested `Control` “collection” to avoid this unnecessary work.

In addition, the question is not really clear on “how” you want to “filter” the grid. For example, the picture shows each column to the left where the user can type into the text to “filter” the grid by the value(s) entered in the text boxes. I would assume that if the user enters text into two (2) or more text boxes, then, the filter would be using an “AND” expression to filter on all the values that the user entered.

This “AND”, “OR” type filter is not clear, in addition, “filtering” on the `Boolean` “checkbox” control may pose a problem in the sense that it may be confusing to the user and will definitely require more work on your part. For example, for the text boxes, it is straight forward for the user to “reset” the filter to “nothing” by “clearing” the text in the text box and clicking the “filter” button again.

However, this is not the case for the checkbox. The user can not “clear” the “checked\unchecked” value. A checkbox is either “checked” or not, even if you set some “tri” state to the checkbox, how would the user “visually” see this “cleared” checkbox?

Given this, when the data is “initially” loaded AND “before” any “filter” is applied, BOTH, checked and unchecked “Status” values will be displayed to the user. However, after the FIRST filter is applied, the user will NEVER be able to “see” BOTH checked and unchecked “Status” values again without some type of “signal” indicating that they want to “ignore” the “Status” value. In the example below A button is added to “reset” the grid back to its original state.

The example below starts with two global variables: `GridTable` and `AllControls`…

```
private DataTable GridTable;
private Dictionary<Control, Type> AllControls;
```

Exposing the grids data source `GridTable` is to keep a copy of the original data and is also used when setting the filter. Each time a new filter is applied, the code uses this table to initially set the “filter”. In addition, the Dictionary `AllControls` is filled using this table.

The `AllControls` `Dictionary` is used as a “collection” of the filter controls along with the “Type” value of the control. Bear in mind it is not absolutely necessary to have this “Type” value since the code is ALWAYS using the same “AND” and EQUALS (“=”) filter expressions, however, if you wanted to filter on a “partial or containing” string value using the “LIKE” keyword, then, we WOULD need to distinguish the “type” to make sure we do not use a “LIKE” keyword on a “numeric” column as it will crash. The same applies to the checkbox columns.

Since the dictionary keeps track of the “Type” of the value, it is convenient to use this value to determine what type of control to use, i.e. a text box for `strings` and numbers and a checkbox for `booleans`.

In this example, initially, the grid uses a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`. When a filter is applied, a `DataView` is created from the original data table, then a filter is applied to this `DataView` and it is used as a `DataSource` to the grid.

Once we have the grids `DataTable`, we can use it to create the `AllControls` `Dictionary`. Here a loop through the table's columns to grab the column name and also the “type” of a column. For `string` and numeric type columns, we add a `TextBox` and its value type (string/int) to the dictionary. For Boolean columns, we add a `CheckBox` to the dictionary. Therefore, a method `GetControlsDictionary` that takes the `GridTable` and returns a `Dictionary<Control, Type>` may come in handy and may look like below…

```
private Dictionary<Control, Type> GetControlsDictionary(DataTable dt) {
  Dictionary<Control, Type> controls = new Dictionary<Control, Type>();
  Control theControl;
  Type valueType;
  foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
    valueType = col.DataType;
    switch (valueType.ToString()) {
      case "System.Int32":
      case "System.String":
        theControl = new TextBox() {
          Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
          Name = col.ColumnName
        };
        break;
      case "System.Boolean":
        theControl = new CheckBox() {
          Name = col.ColumnName,
          CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        };
        break;
      default:
        theControl = new TextBox() {
          Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
          Name = col.ColumnName
        };
        break;
    }
    controls.Add(theControl, valueType);
  }
  return controls;
}
```

With the `AllControls` dictionary, we can create a method `SetFilterControls` that takes the dictionary and sets up the filter text boxes, etc. The code below uses a `TableLayoutPanel` control as the original code does and it may look something like….

```
public void SetFilterControls(Dictionary<Control, Type> controls) {
  int rowIndex = 1;
  foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, Type> controlItem in controls) {
    _tableLayout.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
    _tableLayout.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = controlItem.Key.Name, TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight }, 0, rowIndex);
    _tableLayout.Controls.Add(controlItem.Key, 1, rowIndex++);
  }
}
```

The `AllControls` dictionary will also come in handy when we want to apply a filter to the grid. Building the filter string will require that we loop through the dictionary, check the value of each control then add that value to the filter string. For example, If the user types in “5” in the “ID” filter box, then clicks the filter button, the filter string would look like… “[ID] = ‘5’”. If more than one filter text box has text, then this will create a compound “AND” filter string. For example, If the user types “5” in the “ID” text box AND types “123” in the “PIB” text box, then the filter string will look like… “[ID] = ‘5’ AND [PIB] = ‘123’”. If a user types non-numeric characters into a text box that is matched to a numeric column, then an empty string is returned. In addition, if any text box is empty, then an empty string is returned. This `GetFilterString()` method that loops through the dictionary may look something like…

```
private string GetFilterString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  string curFilter = "";
  List<string> filters = new List<string>();
  foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, Type> item in AllControls) {
    curFilter = GetItemFilterString(item);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(curFilter)) {
      filters.Add(curFilter);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < filters.Count; i++) {
    sb.Append(filters[i]);
    if (i < filters.Count - 1) {
      sb.Append(" AND ");
    }
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Next the `GetItemFilterString(KeyValuePair<Control, Type> item)` method used above, to get each individual control’s filter string. It should be noted that there may be more error checking needed here.

```
private string GetItemFilterString(KeyValuePair<Control, Type> item) {
  switch (item.Value.ToString()) {
    case "System.Int32":
      // if the text is NOT a valid int... then an empty string is returned
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Key.Text) || (!int.TryParse(item.Key.Text, out int value))) {
        return "";
      }
      return "[" + item.Key.Name + "] = '" + item.Key.Text + "'";
    case "System.String":
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Key.Text)) {
        return "";
      }
      return "[" + item.Key.Name + "] = '" + item.Key.Text + "'";
    case "System.Boolean":
      if (((CheckBox)item.Key).Checked) {
        return "[" + item.Key.Name + "] = True";
      }
      return "[" + item.Key.Name + "] = False";
    default:
      return "";
  }
}
```

Next, the filter button clicks the event to use the above method(s) and filter the grid…

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataView dv = new DataView(GridTable);
  dv.RowFilter = GetFilterString();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

As previously mentioned, I added another button to reset the data back to a non-filtered state.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
}
```

Putting all this together may look like….

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridTable = GetDT();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable;
  AllControls = GetControlsDictionary(GridTable);
  SetFilterControls(AllControls);
}


private DataTable GetDT() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("PIB", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Registration Number", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof(bool));
  FillTable(dt);
  return dt;
}

private void FillTable(DataTable dt) {
  Random rand = new Random();
  int pib;
  int reg;
  bool stat;
  for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    pib = rand.Next(0, 20);
    reg = rand.Next(0, 3);
    stat = rand.Next(2) == 1;
    dt.Rows.Add(i, "Name_" + i, pib, reg, stat);
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Huh big answer, give me time to test and analyze

Comment: Thanks for your time. This work and you give me idea how to fix my problem. Thanks so much